# L7x font encoding ellipsis issue

Tags: font-encodings, ellipsis

Can someone explain why does compiler throw an error

> > \f@encoding=macro:
> >     ->T1.
> >     l.5     \makeatletter\show\f@encoding
> >                                         \makeatother
>
> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
>   \textellipsis ->\L7x-cmd \textellipsis 
>                                         \L7x\textellipsis 
>   l.6     \dots
>
> If you really absolutely need more capacity,
>   you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

for this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[L7x,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter\show\f@encoding\makeatother
\dots
\fontencoding{L7x}\selectfont
\makeatletter\show\f@encoding\makeatother
\dots
\end{document}
```

It seems that for the first `\dots` it goes into `L7x` table while the current font encoding is `T1`.

Is that an expected behavior or a bug?

Kind regards, Ivan

**Fix Proposal**

Based on the analysis @David Carlisle has provided below, after digging into other encoding definitions and [`fntguide`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fntguide) I would like to present my proposal for fixing the issue within `l7xenc.def`. WYSIWYM could be easily achieved replacing all these

```
\bgroup
  \def\default@family{lmr}%
  \DeclareFontEncoding{L7x}{}{}
\egroup
\@ifundefined{L7x@default@family}{\@namedef{L7x@default@family}{lmr}}{}
\def\hooked@encoding{L7x}
\DeclareRobustCommand\selectfont
  {%
  \ifx\f@linespread\baselinestretch 
  \else
    \set@fontsize\baselinestretch\f@size\f@baselineskip 
  \fi
  \ifx\f@encoding\hooked@encoding
    \expandafter\ifx\csname \f@encoding+\f@family\endcsname\relax
      \edef\reserved@a{\lowercase{\noexpand\IfFileExists{\f@encoding\f@family.fd}}}%
      \reserved@a\relax{%
        \expandafter\ifx\csname\f@encoding @default@family\endcsname\relax
    \else
          \@font@info{Failed loading font information for \f@encoding+\f@family.}%
      \expandafter\edef\expandafter\f@family\expandafter{\csname\f@encoding @default@family\endcsname}%
    \fi
    }%
    \fi
  \fi
  \xdef\font@name{\csname\curr@fontshape/\f@size\endcsname}%
  \pickup@font
  \font@name
  \size@update
  \enc@update
  }
```

by only these three lines:

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{L7x}{}{}
\DeclareErrorFont{L7x}{lmr}{m}{n}{10}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{L7x}{lmr}{m}{n}
```

In order not to get warnings (saying `cmr` is substituted by `lmr`) one should explicitly use statement `\usepackage{lmodern}` before calling for `fontenc`, satisfying what's written in `fntguide`:

> The font specification for `<encoding><family><series><shape>` must have been defined by `\DeclareFontShape` before the `\begin{document}` is reached.

**Closure**

I'm glad to inform you all that the above Fix Proposal has been included in the latest version of `lithuanian` bundle (version 2017-12-06) maintained by Sig­i­tas Tolušis, along with making `babel`'s `lithuanian` agnostic of font and font encoding. Additionally, missing translations for Proof and Glossary have been defined.

Comment: The warnings are only information. You don't need to load `lmodern` to satisfy what's required here. Personally, I never use `lmodern`.

Comment: I agree with you, although reducing the number of warnings or completely suppressing them gives the impression of how deep one understands what is going on in the background. And that's why I am fond of such approach. :)

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for *any* encoding file to set \DeclareErrorFont. This declaration is a declaration for the whole of NFSS and just because a new encoding gets loaded that declaration shouldn't change. Declaring a substituation set, yes, but not the ErrorFont which is only there if something totally get screwed up and we need a font that is 100% known to be available on the system. So please just take it out.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach It seems to be resolved https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.4503.1678301186.3715.ctan-ann@ctan.org (in March 2023).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top of the file `l7xenc.def`  you will find the lines

```
\bgroup
  \def\default@family{lmr}%
  \DeclareFontEncoding{L7x}{}{}
\egroup
```

defining `\default@family` in a group  doesn't do much and defining the L7x encoding inside a group does not work at all, effectively the encoding is not defined (but enough bits of it get defined that you avoid the high level error checks).

If you change that to

```
%\bgroup
%  \def\default@family{lmr}%
  \DeclareFontEncoding{L7x}{}{}
%\egroup
```

then your example works, but this should be raised with the maintainers of the file, I don't know the intent of the original code.

Specifically what happens is that any encoding specific commands are optimised for the usual case that any given use is usually the same encoding as the previous use, however they are guarded by an internal command `\<enc>-cmd` that detects if a different encoding is in force and switches the command definition.

so `\textellipsis` has the definition

```
\L7x-cmd \textellipsis \L7x\textellipsis
```

which says (or at least is supposed to say) if the encoding is L7x use the optimised version for that encoding, otherwise find a version for the current encoding.

Unfortunately the definition of `\L7x-cmd` was lost at the `\egroup` the line after it was defined, this leaves it defined as `\relax` which does nothing

so `\textellipsis` does `\relax` then calls `\textellipsis` again and you recurse until the stack fills.

Comment: Hi, David.

Thank you for clarifying what actually happens (I will read it over and over until I get the point).

What is the process now in order to fix this for everyone?

Comment: @Ivan there is an email address at the top of `l7xenc.def` can you report it, you could just link to here for details)

Comment: Done. Now we wait...

Comment: Additionally, I have made a thorough search for all `\DeclareFontEncoding` calls in all `*enc.def` files available in MiKTeX. It seems that only `L7x` has such issue. :D

Comment: Citing the maintainer: The additional coding in l7xenc.def was based on idea in any usecase with encoding L7x to use Latin Modern font as many of others do not have non composed lithuanian letters.

Comment: @IvanKokan I don't understand that comment from the L7x maintanier the file is broken as you showed, do the maintainers plan to fix it, or do you mean they were somehow explaining why it is broken?

Comment: The maintainer just wanted to explain the reasons for implementing such (extra) code in the definition, and is aware of the issue.

I wanted to share his reply here, so everyone is aware of it. And maybe we come out with the proper fix, helping the maintainer...

Comment: Ok, I suppose, although hard to guess what fix is required other than remove those lines, but we'll see:-)

Comment: What I also find very confusing is the fact that commenting those three lines doesn't help me completely.

Please check the following excerpt from the log:
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for L7x/cmr/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for L7x+cmr on input line 5. No file L7xcmr.fd. ! LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.
For encoding scheme L7x the defaults cmr/m/n do not form a valid font shape
! Corrupted NFSS tables. wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables} error@fontshape else let f...
l.8 \fontencoding{L7x}\selectfont

Comment: Even adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` before `\usepackage[L7x,T1]{fontenc}` leaves `This NFSS system isn't set up properly...` error message.

Comment: y@IvanKokan yes  declaring the encoding in a group breaks latex, that much at least has to change.

Comment: Fix Proposal added to the bottom of my original post.